# CSS - :before selector not working with leaflet map

Tags: css, angular, leaflet

I am trying to remove the white arrows which Leaflet normally displays on tooltips. When inspecting the site in my browser, I can easily just add `display: none` to the element to remove the arrows:

[image: css-browser]

However, when I try to do the same inside my styles.scss file of my .NET Core 3.1 / Angular application, it doesn't work. This is how I tried to do it (both for left and right arrows):

```
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
    content: none;
}
```

I also tried `display: none` or even `*:before` as the selector but it's also not working. using "::before" instead of ":before" also made no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you inspected the element using your browser dev tools, to check if your rule applied in the first place? And if it perhaps gets overwritten by a more specific one?

Comment: @CBroe It is not applied at all. It seems like no matter what selector I am using, it just gets ignored.

Comment: Well we can’t debug this for you, based on just a screenshot. [mre] required.

Comment: @CBroe I'd be happy to provide one but I have no idea how. I tried to reproduce the problem with jsfiddle but the selector works just fine there, just not in my project. I can modify the tooltips via CSS just fine but for whatever reason I cannot get any access to the :before element.

Comment: stackblitz.com for example provides online playgrounds, where projects using these kinds of frameworks can be demonstrated; but – only showing an online version of your problem, is not how questions are supposed to be asked here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand. I should provide a minimal reproducible example but I'm not supposed to show an online version of the problem? If I understood that correctly then how am I supposed to ask my question properly and what should I provide? I mean, I can't just upload my entire project including all source files and database scripts just to get help with this one problem, but I also can't just take the relevant parts of my code and show them here because it doesn't show the whole picture and cannot be executed by someone else without the rest of the project.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so ideally what you are asking here today, will help other users with similar problems in the future. But for that to work, the problem must be reproducible. And if you only present it on an external platform, then chances are high, that it will disappear from there again at some point - leaving the question here without proper context.

Comment: You can post a link, and see if someone wants to go and have a look at the issue that way – as an _exception_ to the rule; but in general, it is your responsibility here to break it down to a minimal example, that still reproduces your problem. Of course that might not work in every situation - but at some point, that’s simply “tough luck” then, IMHO.